# How do you open extracted images from the MNIST database

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist

Basically, I'm trying to get an image from the MNIST dataset and then show it on my computer. The problem is that when I try to open a single image (using the pillow Image.open() function), it says it can't 'read' it. I can't tell if it's a single thing that's not working or all of it. Really, I'm just messing around with new stuff.

I tried using the 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist', but it just keeps mucking up, I don't know why. Then I decided that I should just download the MNIST data and open that and now it's saying it can't 'read' 'numpy.ndarray'.

```py
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import extract_images, extract_labels

with open('train-images-idx3-ubyte (2).gz', 'rb') as f:
  train_images = extract_images(f)
with open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte (1).gz', 'rb') as f:
  train_labels = extract_labels(f)

with open('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'rb') as f:
  test_images = extract_images(f)
with open('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'rb') as f:
  test_labels = extract_labels(f)

myImage = Image.open(train_images[0])
myImage.show()
```

I expected it to open the file but it just shows up with an error about opening `train_images[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out the answer.

What you needed to do was change the shape of the data using `np.reshape()` and then use `Image.fromarray()` instead of `Image.open()`.
For example:

```py
MyImage = train_images[0]
MyImage = MyImage.reshape(28, 28)
MyImage = Image.fromarray(MyImage)
```